# set array elements using new

Tags: c++, arrays

There is that way to set elements on array - `int rgArrayNum [] = {16, 2, 77, 40, 12071};`
How can I do same way on pointer with new   ? I tried `int *pArrayNum = new  [] = {4 ,3 ,3} ;` but it didn't worked   .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), you can write:

```
int *pArrayNum = new int[3]{4, 3, 3};
```

However, in [c++03](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03) array new initialization is not allowed; you'd have to initialize the members individually or by copy from an array on the stack:

```
int rgArrayNum [] = {16, 2, 77, 40, 12071};
int *pArrayNum = new int[sizeof rgArrayNum / sizeof rgArrayNum[0]];
std::copy(&rgArrayNum[0], &rgArrayNum[sizeof rgArrayNum / sizeof rgArrayNum[0]],
    pArrayNum);
```

Comment: You'll need a `[3]` there; it won't infer the size from the initialiser list.

Comment: @ecatmur: I tried your code and got error "no matching function for call to 'copy(int [5], int&, int*&)'"  . I added #include <algorithm> . What I did not true ?

Comment: @URL87 I forgot a `&` on the second parameter.  Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

In C++03 and earlier, you can't initialise the values of a dynamic array to anything except zero.

You can achieve something similar in C++11:

```
int *pArrayNum = new int [3] {4, 3, 3};
```

or if you don't mind using a container to manage the memory for you:

```
std::vector<int> array = {4, 3, 3};
```

Comment: While `vector` is without a doubt the superior answer, you can actually do it without a container `new int[3] { 4, 3, 3 };`. I don't see why anyone would want to, though.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: So you can. I've learnt something today.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: It wat only example .. I mean dynamic element's count .

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the array not with integers but with integer pointers.

```
int* rgArrayNum2 [] = {new int(16), new int(16), new int(16), new int(16), new int(16)};

//test
int* test = rgArrayNum2[2];
*test = 15;
```

now rgArrayNum2[2] is 15.